# Events on a youtube iframe inside a bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, youtube-api

I am having trouble understanding why I can't get at events of a youtube iframe when the video is in a modal that has its iframe property added via jquery that it gets from the link that launches the modal.

If I place the SRC in the iframe tag manually and run, everything works as expected.

I have created two codepens to illustrate this.

https://codepen.io/nick-jlsa/pen/GPZogZ

First this is the codepen that works as expected. The button launches a modal, the modal has an iframe with a youtube video SRC. The border color of the video is changed depending on the player status. This is working great. But the video SRC must already be in the iframe tag. I need the iframe tag to be populated by the link that launches it.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="play-video">
  launch and play youtube video
</button>

<iframe id="player" width="100%" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ALUKDkOxVPo?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="border: solid 4px #37474F"></iframe>
```

====================

https://codepen.io/nick-jlsa/pen/gZrPeR

Second is a codepen showing that when the iframe src is injected via jQuery on link click, the player events cannot be seen by JS.

```
<a class="launch-video-modal clickable" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALUKDkOxVPo"><span class="text"><span class="text-inner">Watch Now</span></span></a>

<iframe id="player" width="100%" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="border: solid 4px #37474F"></iframe>

$('a.launch-video-modal').click(function() {
    var theModal = $(this).data("target"),
    videoSRC = $(this).attr("data-video"),
    splitter = '?v=',
    indexOf = videoSRC.indexOf(splitter),

    videoID = videoSRC.slice(indexOf+splitter.length);

    videoSRCauto = "//youtube.com/embed/" + videoID + "?modestbranding=1&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&html5=1&autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1";
    $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRCauto);
    $(theModal + ' button.close').click(function () {
    $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRC);
    });
});
```

Comment: Could it be a timing issue? Is it possible that your script is executing before the contents of the frame have loaded?

Comment: @Vlnflt yes i am thinking that it is an execution order problem. But I can't seem to find the right recipe. Any ideas on how to refactor so that it fires in order? I am open to changing the way the SRC is populated. I just need a way that two different links can load two different videos in a single modal. This is in a CMS so a given page might have 1 or 20 video links that all open in the same modal.